# :hover = children show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

Achieve this: https://jsfiddle.net/7uuybqbo/

```css
#p1 {
 display: none;
}

#page1:hover + #p1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="pg">
            <div class="pgButton" id="page1">1</div>
            <div id="p1" class="hide">
                page 1
            </div>
        </div>
```

My struggle: As small amount of code as possible, that will achieve the result with multiple pages shown in this attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/7tw03cyj/

```css
.hide {
            display: none;
        }
        
        .pgButton:hover + .pg > div {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="pg">
            <div class="pgButton" id="page1">1</div>
            <div id="p1" class="hide">
                page 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pg">
            <div class="pgButton" id="page2">2</div>
            <div id="p2" class="hide">
                page 2
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: `.pg > div` refers to the same `.pgButton` `div`. Why not simply `.pgButton:hover + div`?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for? You can use the `.hide` attribute as the qualifier.

```css
.hide {
            display: none;
        }
        
        .pgButton:hover + .hide {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="pg">
            <div class="pgButton" id="page1">1</div>
            <div id="p1" class="hide">
                page 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pg">
            <div class="pgButton" id="page2">2</div>
            <div id="p2" class="hide">
                page 2
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for multiple instances:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}

.pg .pgButton:hover + .hide {
    display: block;
}
```